# Should changes be made to the e-mail client or actual e-mail account itself?

Tags: gmail, synchronization, outlook

Sometimes I'm unsure if I should change Outlook or the Gmail settings. For example, I noticed both Gmail and Outlook asked me for my real name. I'm connecting by IMAP.

- Why is this and what happens if they are different?
- If I wanted to create a new folder and filter should this be done through Outlook or Gmail?
- For example if I wanted to create a new folder where all messages containing `Rogers communications` in the subject would automatically go, should this be done in Gmail or Outlook?
- What if I wanted to block an address, should this be done in Gmail or Outlook?

Comment: Are you talking about accessing Gmail from Outlook via IMAP or POP?

Comment: IMAP...................

Comment: I would edit that into your question to clarify, then.  Others have found the question unclear as it is written.